# Linq query with one to many relation

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have two entites in my asp.net MVC3 application and I am using EF 4.1. Entities are:

```
public class Category {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set; }
    public int Price {get; set;}
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I want to calculate sum of prices of all movies where  category name = "Comedy" using Linq query. Can you please suggest me Linq query using extension method ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have an `IEnumerable<Movie> movies`, you can do

```
movies
    .Where(x => x.Category.Name == "Comedy")
    .Select(x => x.Price)
    .Sum();
```

As @Linkgoron says in the comment, you can also put the predicate in the `Sum` method, such as:

```
movies
    .Where(x => x.Category.Name == "Comedy")
    .Sum(x => x.Price);
```

Comment: I think that movies.Where(x => x.Category.Name == "Comedy").Sum(x => x.Price) is a bit better

Comment: @Linkgoroun: what if I need to find MAX of category.id of category where movie price > 100

Comment: @smartcaveman err... I was happy before, just wanted to comment about another option. No offence meant.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, you need the Maximum category Id?  Or the category Id of the category containing the movie with the maximum price?

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, seems like a strange criteria, but assuming you have `IEnumerable<Category> categories`, do `categories.Where(c => c.Movies.Any(m => m.Price > 100)).Max(x => x.Id);`

Comment: @smartcaveman: what if I dont have IEnumerable<Category> ? This is not the actual situation, I am using this example for my real project where I need to find sum of something in primary key where both primary and foreign entities have join

Comment: @DotnetSparrow, if you don't have `IEnumerable<Category>` then you can get one (although it will be missing any categories without movies) using `movies.Select(x => x.Category).Distinct();`   You could also perform the query like `movies.Where(x => x.Price > 100).Max(x => x.Category.Id);`